# App crashes after rename the package and changing the main activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have made my app about travelling but after I renamed package and I changed the order of the activities I have problems with my app. I get error "app keeps stopping". Here is my logcat.

```
09-29 22:58:39.192 15046-15046/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide, PID: 15046
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide/com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.EditText
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2729)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1505)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.EditText
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.EditText
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.EditText" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.Andrea.Diplomska.TravelGuide.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:35)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6673)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2682)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1505)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
```

Comment: `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.EditText`

Comment: It looks like you have an `<android.support.design.widget.EditText>` element in the layout you're passing to `setContentView()` in `LoginActivity`. There is no such `View` as `android.support.design.widget.EditText`. Did you mean `<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText>`?

Comment: did you forget any thing of rename your package -- there are 3 different places ( gradle - Mainactivity - package it self )

Comment: There's some problem with the EditText in your layout of LoginActivity.   Please post your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you create another project with the right name and pass all data to new project, because android studio create many files and routes in runtime with your package name but if you only need change the application id could you  change this info in your gradle file.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: why? what's the root cause? Its not a solution